# Number of columns in dataset

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to find the number of columns a data set has?

I know we can find the length of rows with:

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows.length
```

Is there something similar for counting or returning the length of the columns?

Comment: ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count should work.

Comment: The `DataSet` has tables, a `DataTable` has columns. Btw, `ds.Tables[0].Rows.length` doesn't compile for two reasons: 1. .NET is case sensitive 2. the property is not `Length` but `Count`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should look the properties of `DataTable` before asking this. As it should work.

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
```

Comment: can you show us the code where this error is coming? because it should work as expected.

Comment: Give it a name `int colCount = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;`

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`DataTable.Columns.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.internaldatacollectionbase.count.aspx) property. So `ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count`.

If you have a `DataRow` you can also use this property via...

```
int columnCount = row.Table.Columns.Count;
```

or another option is the `DataRow.ItemArray` which contains all fields:

```
int columnCount = row.ItemArray.Length;
```